# Handling WF 4.0 long running activity using TPL

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I created an activity which executes a web request and stores the result into the database. Usually this process takes about 1 hour and it makes workflow engine to behave abnormally. I found out that for these long running activities I should write some different code so that the workflow engine thread won't be blocked.

Studying some blogs about writing long running activities I understand that I should use `Bookmark` concept. But I didn't any solution using TPL and `Task`.

Is this code correct for handling a long running activity using `Task`s?

```
public sealed class WebSaveActivity : NativeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.CreateBookmark("websave", (activityContext, bookmark, value) =>
        {

        });

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            GetAndSave(); // This takes 1 hour to accomplish.
            context.RemoveBookmark("websave");
        });

    }

    protected override bool CanInduceIdle 
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `StartNew` should be used with caution, consider use `Run`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just saw your related question here: [How to write a long running activity to call web services in WF 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619188/how-to-write-a-long-running-activity-to-call-web-services-in-wf-4-0)

Another way is to implement your activity is as an `AsyncCodeActivity`:

```
namespace MyLibrary.Activities
{
    using System;
    using System.Activities;

    public sealed class MyActivity : AsyncCodeActivity
    {
        protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            var delegateToLongOperation = new Func<bool>(this.LongRunningSave);
            context.UserState = delegateToLongOperation;
            return delegateToLongOperation.BeginInvoke(callback, state);
        }

        protected override void EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
        {
            var longOperationDelegate = (Func<bool>) context.UserState;
            var longOperationResult = longOperationDelegate.EndInvoke(result);

            // Can continue your activity logic here.
        }

        private bool LongRunningSave()
        {
            // Logic to perform the save.
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The workflow instance stays in memory, but at the very least the workflow runtime can handle its normal scheduling tasks without one of its threads being taken up by a long running process.

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not the way bookmarks should be used. A bookmark is used when the workflow has to wait for input from an external process.

For example: I have a document approval workflow and at some point in time the workflow has to wait for a human reviewer to give an OK on the document. Instead of keeping the workflow instance in memory the workflow will be idled and activated again by the runtime when `ResumeBookmark` is called.

In your situation your workflow cannot be idled since it has an operation running in its context. That operation is your task that, by the way, is a fire-and-forget tasks so critical failures cannot be handled by the WF.

Now, for a possible solution you might consider to have an other process call the `GetAndSave` method and have that process ultimately call the `ResumeBookmark` on the WF so the workflow can be idled by the runtime. That process could even be the same process that hosts your workflow.

For an example see [this blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bursteg/2009/05/19/wf-4-0-long-running-custom-activities-with-bookmarks-and-nativeactivity/). Just image that instead of waiting for a human to enter something in the console your long running task is performed.

You did not specify what comes after your activity but do note that it is possible to return data back to the workflow when the bookmark is resumed. So any result of the `GetAndSave`, even if it is just an error code you can use to decide how to further go along with the other activities in your workflow.

Hope this makes sense to you and you see what I try to outline as a possible solution.

**EDIT**
A quick note about using Tasks or async/await in WF. There are AFAIK no methods to override that return Tasks so you either have to make them block by using `.Wait()` or `.Result` or forget about it. Because if you cannot await them bad things will happen during workflow execution because other activities might be started before the one using Tasks has completed its work.

When the WF runtime was developed the whole concept of Tasks was still very young so the WF runtime did not / does not cater for them.

**EDIT 2:** 
example implementation (Based on [this excellent official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee149789(v=vs.110).aspx))

Your activity will be almost empty:

```
public sealed class TriggerDownload : NativeActivity<string>
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> BookmarkName { get; set; }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        // Create a Bookmark and wait for it to be resumed.
        context.CreateBookmark(BookmarkName.Get(context),
            new BookmarkCallback(OnResumeBookmark));
    }

    protected override bool CanInduceIdle
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void OnResumeBookmark(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object obj)
    {
       // When the Bookmark is resumed, assign its value to
       // the Result argument. (This depends on whether you have a result on your GetData method like a string with a result code or something)
       Result.Set(context, (string)obj);
    }
}
```

It signals the workflow runtime that the workflow can be idled and how it can be resumed.

Now, for the workflow runtime configuration:

```
WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(<Your WF>);

// Workflow lifecycle events omitted except idle.
AutoResetEvent idleEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);


wfApp.Idle = delegate(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
{
    idleEvent.Set();
};

// Run the workflow.
wfApp.Run();

// Wait for the workflow to go idle before starting the download
idleEvent.WaitOne();

// Start the download and resume the bookmark when finished.
var result = await Task.Run(() => GetAndSave());
BookmarkResumptionResult result = wfApp.ResumeBookmark(new Bookmark("GetData"), result);

// Possible BookmarkResumptionResult values:
// Success, NotFound, or NotReady
Console.WriteLine("BookmarkResumptionResult: {0}", result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so what do you suggest for writing such activity?

Comment: This approach requires to modify the workflow application which I have not access to. I'm looking for a solution to handle all required code in my activity, not with modifying the server.

Comment: Ah missed that critical part in the question :-) Anyway, all build-in mechanismes like bookmarks or host communications are out of the question then.  Async/await is just not supported and since you cannot use Tasks in WF without using a blocking wait for their completing it will be impossible to create an activity that takes a long time but does not block the workflow thread.